# "достичь" vs. "достигнуть"

Tags: глаголы, суффиксы, история-языка

Словарь указывает оба варианта как допустимые. Но хотя *достичь* и считается основным, в его спряжении все равно присутствуют формы с суффиксом *-ну \ -н*: *достигну*, *достигнешь*, и т.п.

Как получилось, что в глаголе появился (или исчез?) суффикс *-ну \ -н*? Существовали ли когда-нибудь формы, аналогичные формам *достигну*, *достигнешь* по значению, но не имевшие суффикса?

Comment: "Существовали ли когда-нибудь формы, аналогичные формам достигну, достигнешь по значению, но не имевшие суффикса -ну?" - I am sorry, but isn't it like -н- is the суффикс in достигну, and -у is an окончание?

Comment: You're right. I'll change the question.

Answer (score 3):

раньше была разница между лексическими значениями суффикс *ну* обозначает одноразовое действие (например, это очень ясно в паре прыгать/прыгнуть), но в некоторых формах сейчас суффикс теряет свое значение

Comment: Вы полагаете, суффикс "ну" обозначал одноразовое действие даже в словах "погибнуть", "виснуть" или "мерзнуть"? Или это новейшие образования?

Comment: В «прыгать - прыгнуть» дело скорее не одноразовости, а совершенности, как например в «колоться - кольнуться», «погибать - погибнуть», «достигать - достигнуть». С другой стороны «виснуть» и «мерзнуть» - несовершенные с «-н-», а «достичь» - совершенный без «-н-».

Answer (score 2):

На [Gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_183) есть следующая информация об этом глаголе:

> В русском языке встречаются двоякие формы инфинитивов нескольких
>   глаголов: с формантами -бегнуть (напр., избегнуть - избечь), -стигнуть
>   (напр., достигнуть - достичь) и глагола стынуть - стыть. В современном
>   литературном языке вариативны тоько последние два форманта. Причем
>   среди приставочных глаголов с корневой морфемой стыть сегодня уже не
>   имеет вариантов наиболее употребительный глагол застыть; менее
>   употребительные настынуть, простынуть отмечены в орфографическом
>   словаре как вариантные (настынуть - настыть, простынуть - простыть).
>   По-видимому употребительность влияет на закрепление в языке более
>   экономной формы (без суффикса -ну). Среди глаголов с формантом
>   -стигнуть встречаются обе формы, употребительные уже во времена А. С. Пушкина. Например: Чего он обязан достигнуть? (В. Тендряков. Свидание
>   с Нефертити); ...тогда они могут постичь необъятность вселенной только
>   по звездам (А. Зегерс. Через океан). Более употребительный в языке СМИ
>   глагол достичь преобладает в бессуфиксном варианте. В разговорном
>   языке для обоих глаголов явно предпочитается более короткий вариант:
>   достичь, постичь.

Важным, по-видимому, является упоминание формант. Форманта - термин, обозначающий акустическую характеристику звуков речи (прежде всего гласных), связанную с уровнем частоты голосового тона и образующую тембр звука.

Это позволяет нам предположить, что причины для изменения слова были чисто фонетическими - вместо достаточно длинного варианта "стигнуть" стал использоваться гораздо более короткий вариант "стичь". Причем если на письме разница не так заметна, то в разговорной речи она становится очевидной. В то же время формы "достигну", "достигнешь" и т.д. не претерпели этих изменений, и остались в своем первоначальном виде. Справедливости ради стоит отметить, что сложно представить себе как можно сократить эти слова аналогичным образом.

Comment: Нет, тут термин форманта обозначает не частоту основного тона голоса, а форму слова. Про причины появления двух форм там ничего не сказано.

Comment: Ха ха достижешь, достигу :-)