# Why we say "расторг" but "моргнул"

Tags: глаголы

There are verbs with "-гнуть" ending, for example, `ввергнуть`, `расторгнуть`, `моргнуть`.

First two examples have following form in past time: `вверг`, `расторг`, but for "моргнуть" we have `моргнул`.

Can one give a reasonable explanation of the fact that this verbs are conjugated differently?

**UPD:** It worth to mention in this question that each of these verbs make up so called aspectual pair with imperfect form: ввергать, расторгать, моргать. And, actually, forms `ввергнул`, `расторгнул` are completely valid, as well as shortened forms. But this does not give me a hint )

Comment: I think that the answer to this question may also shed light on [the question about достичь and достигнуть](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/904).

Comment: I guess you are right. In both cases this is about some peculiarities in aspectual pairs. Let's see do these pecularities have common root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [study](http://www.philol.msu.ru/~ccs/files/nesset.pdf) which states that Proto-Slavic has two different suffixes `-нѫти`: one used for semelfactives (quanta of repetitive actions, expressed by such called multiplicatives), another one used for inchoatives and terminatives (verbs meaning "entering or leaving a continuous state").

Traditionally, in Russian they are denoted simply as perfective / imperfective aspects, but Plungian's theory states that these categories should be further extended.

Examples of multiplicatives (repetitive actions) and corresponding semelfactives (quanta of these actions):

> - стучать / стукнуть
> - кричать / крикнуть
> - чихать / чихнуть
> - моргать / моргнуть

Examples on continuatives ("being in a state") and corresponding inchoatives / terminatives ("entering / leaving a state"):

> - замолкать / замолкнуть
> - замерзать / замёрзнуть
> - погибать / погибнуть

The study states that (though with numerous exceptions) semelfactives retain the suffix and inchoatives / terminatives lose it.

An interesting example would be the verb *дрогнуть* which has both meanings.

As a semelfactive, it retains the suffix:

> Звездолет дрогнул несколько раз, точно успокаивающийся зверь, и замер. *[И. А. Ефремов. Час быка (1968-1969)]*

As a continuative, it loses it:

> Видно, кто в этой шкуре не бывал, на морозе не дрог, тот нашего брата постигнуть и понять не может… потому ― душа зачерствела… *[С. П. Подъячев. Мытарства (1903)]*